# Need equivalent command for "oc secret new-basicauth" which is deprecated in openshift

Tags: openshift, redhat

I am following this guide (https://github.com/3scale/apicast) to create an environment with apicast and openshift.

The guide says that I need to create a secret using  "oc secret new-basicauth"  but I get the following message after executing the command.

`> oc secret new-basicauth apicast-configuration-url-secret --password=https://ACCESS-TOKEN@ACCOUNT-admin.3scale.net`

`> Command "new-basicauth" is deprecated, use oc create secret`

I understand that the command is deprecated and I need to use "oc create secret" instead.  However, I do not know how to use the new command to achieve the same result, which is creating a new-basicauth.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and following the docs it seems that the following command might do the trick:

```
oc create secret generic gitlab-credentials \
  --from-literal=username=<user_name> \
  --from-literal=password=<password> \
  --type=gitlab.com/basic-auth
```

*"gitlab-credentials"* here is the secret name.

Then, if you want to create an app using the secret you just created:

```
oc new-app \
  <imagestream-chosen>~<git-repo-url> \
  --context-dir=<context-dir> \
  --allow-missing-imagestream-tags \
  --source-secret=gitlab-credentials
```

The **--source-secret** gets the previously created secret.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I had to tweak matthieusb answer a little bit for it to work for me. Note I was doing basic auth against github.com not gitlab.com. So for the sake of people in a similiar situtation as me, I am putting this answer up.

I consulted the Kubernetes secret builtin types found here, keep in mind Openshift is built on top of Kubernetes: [Secrets | Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/)

I merely changed the type to kubernetes.io/basic-auth, I guessed this is the one I wanted since I was doing basic auth against github.com:

```
oc create secret generic gitlab-credentials \
  --from-literal=username=<user_name> \
  --from-literal=password=<password> \
  --type=kubernetes.io/basic-auth
```

This ended up being enough for the `oc new-app` to work for me.

One thing to note is that even though that command is deprecated you can still use it. I used it to confirm that the yaml generated for the secret is the same for the yaml of the non deprecated command above.

In fact, according to the 4.7 Release Notes, deprecated features are still supported but not recommended as they will be eventually removed.
[Openshift Container Platform ... release notes](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.7/release_notes/ocp-4-7-release-notes.html#ocp-4-7-deprecated-removed-features)

Comment: the `type=kubernetes.io/basic-auth` worked for me too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for oc create secret reference, the following link is helpful.

https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.9/dev_guide/builds/build_inputs.html#source-secrets-basic-authentication